# How do a reference a local file in a WebView within a windows store app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webview, windows-store-apps

I have a rich text editor which uses `contentEditable` inside a `WebView`, loaded with `NavigateToString`. I've been linking to a web copy of jquery in my editor, but this means the app only works online. I want to switch to sourcing the file locally.

- My jQuery file is here `Assets\HTML\jquery-2.1.0.min.js`
- `Copy To Output Directory` is set to `Copy If Newer`
- `Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js` doesn't work
- `/Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js` doesn't work
- `./Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js` doesn't work
- `~/Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js` doesn't work
- `ms-app:///Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js` doesn't work
- `ms-appx:///Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js` doesn't work
- `ms-appdata:///Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js` doesn't work
- `ms-appdatax:///Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js` doesn't work

I don't get any errors, my jQuery based scripts just don't run.

Anyone got any suggestions? `

Comment: Did you try "Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"? What error are you getting?

Comment: yes, tried that. Not getting an error, just scripts that rely on jquery don't run. if I could access javascript debugger I'm sure it would show me an error along the lines of `$ is not defined`

Comment: use path like "ms-appx-web:///Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"

Comment: @Sungathi thank you, that worked. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use path like this "ms-appx-web:///Assets/HTML/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" it works fine on webview